# VBA Webscrape HTML Coinmarketcap

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Trying to scrape the number of cryptos in the top left corner of https://coinmarketcap.com/. I tried to find the "tr" but could not. Not sure how to grab that value up the top left of the page.

Here is what I have so far and I am being thrown a runtime error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
 Sub cRYP()

 Dim appIE As Object
 Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

  With appIE
  .Navigate "https://coinmarketcap.com/"
  .Visible = True
 End With

 Do While appIE.Busy
 DoEvents
 Loop
 Set allRowOfData = appIE.Document.getElementById("__next")

  Dim myValue As String: myValue = 
  allRowOfData.Cells(16).innerHTML

  appIE.Quit

  Range("A1").Value = myValue

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *tr tag*, because there is no *table*. At first you must get the html structure which contains your wanted value, because there is no possibility to get it directly. That is the structure with the classname `container`. Because the method `getElementsByClassName()` builds a node collection you must get the right structure with it's index in the collection. That's easy because its the first one. The first index of a collection is `0` like in an array.

Than you have this html structure:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><span class="sc-2bz68i-0 cVPJov">Cryptos
      <!-- -->: &nbsp;<a href="/" class="cmc-link">17.826</a>
    </span><span class="sc-2bz68i-0 cVPJov">Exchanges
      <!-- -->: &nbsp;<a href="/rankings/exchanges/" class="cmc-link">459</a>
    </span><span class="sc-2bz68i-0 cVPJov">Market Cap
      <!-- -->: &nbsp;<a href="/charts/" class="cmc-link">€1,536,467,483,857</a>
    </span><span class="sc-2bz68i-0 cVPJov">24h Vol
      <!-- -->: &nbsp;<a href="/charts/" class="cmc-link">€105,960,257,048</a>
    </span><span class="sc-2bz68i-0 cVPJov">Dominance
      <!-- -->: &nbsp;<a href="/charts/#dominance-percentage" class="cmc-link">BTC
        <!-- -->:
        <!-- -->42.7%
        <!-- -->&nbsp;
        <!-- -->ETH
        <!-- -->:
        <!-- -->18.2%
      </a>
    </span><span class="sc-2bz68i-0 cVPJov"><span class="icon-Gas-Filled" style="margin-right:4px;vertical-align:middle"></span>ETH Gas
      <!-- -->: &nbsp;<a>35
        <!-- -->
        <!-- -->Gwei<span class="sc-2bz68i-1 cEFmtT icon-Chevron-down"></span>
      </a>
    </span></div>
  <div class="rz95fb-0 jKIeAa">
    <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 cPgeGh nav-item"></div>
    <div class="rz95fb-1 rz95fb-2 eanzZL">
      <div class="cmc-popover">
        <div class="cmc-popover__trigger"><button title="Change your language" class="sc-1kx6hcr-0 eFEgkr"><span class="sc-1b4wplq-1 kJnRBT">English</span><span class="sc-1b4wplq-0 ifkbzu"><span class="icon-Caret-down"></span></span></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rz95fb-1 cfBxiI">
      <div><button title="Select Currency" data-qa-id="button-global-currency-picker" class="sc-1kx6hcr-0 eFEgkr"><span class="sc-1q0bpva-0 hEPBWj"></span><span class="sc-1bafwtq-1 dUQeWc">EUR</span><span class="sc-1bafwtq-0 cIzAJN"><span class="icon-Caret-down"></span></span></button></div>
    </div><button type="button" class="sc-1kx6hcr-0 rz95fb-6 ccLqrB cmc-theme-picker cmc-theme-picker--day"><span class="icon-Moon"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the wanted value is part of the first *a tag* in the scraped structure. We can simply get that tag with the method `getElementsByTagName()`. This will also build a node collection. We need also the first element of the collection with the index `0`.

Than we have this:

```html
<a href="/" class="cmc-link">17.826</a>
```

Now we only need the `innertext` of this element and that's it.

Here is the VBA code. I don't use the IE, because it is finaly EOL and shouldn't be used anymore. You can load coinmarketcap simply without any parameters via xhr (xml http request):

```
Sub CryptosCount()

  Const url As String = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"
  Dim doc As Object
  Dim nodeCryptosCount As Object
  
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
      Set nodeCryptosCount = doc.getElementsByClassName("container")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
      MsgBox "Number of cryptocurrencies on Coinmarketcap: " & nodeCryptosCount.innertext
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

### Edit

As I see now, there is a possibility to get the value directly by using
`getElementsByClassName("cmc-link")(0)`

You can play with the code to learn more.

Comment: Will do Zwenn, I have 0 knowledge of html and this is my first attempt at webs scraping. Ty for the explanations here. I learned a lot.

Comment: I am still hitting the exact same runtime error even with this new and improved vba code. I think am simple just not enabling the correct references. Any advice here?

Comment: @user17420363 Unfortunately, I can't tell you why it doesn't work for you. Did you run the code I posted? For me, a message box is then displayed with the correct value. Did you try to replace the line `Set nodeCryptosCount = doc.getElementsByClassName("container")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)` with my edit `Set nodeCryptosCount = doc.getElementsByClassName("cmc-link")(0)`